# How to cat files together based on charset enconding

Tags: bash, macos, shell, character-encoding

I have a bunch of .txt files in different encodings. I need to `cat` them together based on encoding. So far I've come up with this, but I don't know how to `cat` them together.

`file -I *.txt | grep "charset=iso"` (which returns me all the files that are iso encoded. Now I just want to `cat * >> all.txt` so to speak).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do that

`file -i *.txt | grep 'charset=iso' | cut -d ':' -f1 | xargs -I '{}' cat '{}' >> all-iso.txt`

PS: Tested on Linux on which file command accepts `-i` switch instead of `-I`.

Comment: The `grep -l` option "lists" files (without displaying any grep targets). `man grep` ;-) . `xargs` stuff is good! Good luck to all.

Comment: @luis-muñoz thank you so much! It might be a simple feat for bash lords, but I've yet to master the shell. This saved me a lot of headache, really! Wish I'd asked much sooner, but I'm so stubborn ^_^;

Comment: :) You can combine your stubbornness with  `man` pages and good online material to get good results. Don't give up on bash, it's powerful and very helpful no matter what your main language is.